# displaying values from sequelize query using handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js, sequelize.js

I have a Cart model with product_price and quantity. I am writing a sequelize query to calculate the total as price * quantity
Here's my query

db.Cart.findAll({

```
    attributes: {include: [[db.sequelize.condition(db.sequelize.col('cart_quantity'), '*', db.sequelize.col('price')),'tot']]}

})
```

Sequelize documentatoin says to access the value of 'tot' we use 
instance.get('tot').
So in the results console.log(item.get('tot') displays correct value

.then(function(dbCart) {
      //We have access to the products as an argument inside of the callback function

```
  dbCart.forEach(function(item){
    console.log(item.get('tot'));
  });
  var hbsObject = {
    products: dbCart,
  };
res.render("shop/cart", hbsObject);
});
```

});

Now when I try to access the value in my carts.handlebars file
I am unable to display or access the value of 'tot'
{{# each products }}
  {{tot}}
or
{{Cart.tot}} or {{products.tot}} or {{products.get('tot')}} yields no value 
{{/each}}
How do I access and display the value of 'tot' in handlebars?
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
{{#each users}}
    {{#dataValues}}
        <p>Username: {{username}}</p>
        <p>Email: {{email}}</p>
    {{/dataValues}}
{{/each}}
```

Or try:

```
{{#each users}}
    <p>Username: {{this.dataValues.username}}</p>
    <p>Email: {{this.dataValues.email}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell you can only access the result of the query with item.get('tot'), but since you can't call functions from handlebars you need a work around. One way to do it is to add a handlebars helper that just wraps the .get() function.

```
const Handlebars = require('handlebars');
Handlebars.registerHelper('sequelizeGet', function(obj, col) {
  return obj.get(col);
});
```

And in the handlebars template access that helper like:

```
<span>{{sequelizeGet item 'tot'}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT 08/02/2022 :

If you want to access values from your models just like you would any other JSON object, you need to serialize them.

I found the quickest and easiest way to do that is with [sequelize-json-schema](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-json-schema) and [sequelize-serialize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-serialize)

In the file where you define your models :

```js
import sjs from 'sequelize-json-schema'

// ... define models with sequelize.define()
const Person = sequelize.define('Person', {name: DataTypes.STRING});

// generate JSON schemas
const schemas = sjs.getSequelizeSchema(sequelize).definitions

// ^ note that I'm only exporting "definitions" because I don't need the rest of the JSON schema

//make sure to export schemas to use it in your app
export {
  sequelize,
  schemas,
  Person
  //...
}
```

Then, when you need to use your models :

```js
//import your models AND the schemas
import { Person, ..., schemas } from '../yourmodels.js'

//import the serialize method from sequelize-serialize
import serialize from 'sequelize-serialize'

//use it to serialize your result
Person.findOne({where: {foo: 'bar'}}).then(model => {
  const person = serialize(model, schemas.person)
  // you can now use 'person' in your view and access its properties
});
```